# ImportError: cannot import name 'Comment'

Tags: python, django, deployment

I'm getting the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Comment'

When I'm attempting to run the following code in the admin.py directory:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Comment
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Comment)
```

I tried to fix the problem myself looking at the documentation, but I can't find anything.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=288)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

        def approve_comments(self):
            return self.comments.filter(approve_comments=True)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("post_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title



    class Comment(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
        author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        text = models.TextField()
        create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
        approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        def approve(self):
            self.approved_comment = True
            self.save()

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post_list')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.text
```

Comment: Can you show us your models?

Comment: Edited post with models inside.

Comment: But you're able to import Post? And why do you have class Comment inside of class Post?

Comment: @DavidHexynator is your indentation same for comment class in actual code as pasted here ?

Answer (score 2):

Change it so the Class Comment is outside of the class post:
Like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=288)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

        def approve_comments(self):
            return self.comments.filter(approve_comments=True)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("post_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title



class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```